# how to subscribe multiple buttons to a event using for loop

Tags: c#, uwp

When i tried to use a list of buttons and a for loop to subscribe selective buttons from the list to an event, the error 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'GamePage.ChessBlock_clicked(object, RoutedEventArgs)' appears and i have no idea how to resolve this, i just need to have each of the selective buttons to be able to access the "chessBlock_clicked" method if they are clicked. Help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

```
static List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        public void ListofBlocks()
        {
            Button[] Blocks =
            {
                    Block1, Block2, Block3, Block4, Block5, Block6, Block7, Block8, Block9, Block10,
                    Block11, Block12, Block13, Block14, Block15, Block16, Block17, Block18, Block19, Block20,

                  // and more blocks
            };

            buttons.AddRange(Blocks);
        }


public static void Determine_turn()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count; i++)
            {
                ChessPiece piece = (ChessPiece)buttons[i].Tag;
                if (Global.Turn == "white")
                {
                    if (piece == ChessPiece.WPawn || piece == ChessPiece.WKnight || piece == ChessPiece.WRook || piece == ChessPiece.WBishop || piece == ChessPiece.WQueen || piece == ChessPiece.WKing)
                    {
                        buttons[i].Click += ChessBlock_clicked;  // error occurs here
                    }
                }
                else if (Global.Turn == "black")
                {

                }
            }
        }


private void ChessBlock_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (sender is Button btn)
            {

                ChessPiece piece = (ChessPiece)btn.Tag;
                Global.SelectedPiece = piece.ToString();

                int index;
                Button destination = null;

                switch (piece)
                {
                    case ChessPiece.WPawn:
                        textBox3.Text = "W pawn";

                        index = buttons.IndexOf(btn);
                        destination = buttons[(index + 8) % buttons.Count];
                        Global.SelectedBtn = buttons[(index) % buttons.Count];

                        destination.Click += destination_clicked;

                        break;

                     // and other cases
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Where did you declare `ChessBlock_clicked`? Can you show it?

Comment: Where did you declare `buttons`? And how?

Comment: Please see revised post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a static method. `ChessBlock_clicked` is not. A static method can't call an instance (non-static) method.

There are a few ways to fix this. The simplest is that if this method needs to access a non-static method, it shouldn't be static.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, this seems to have fixed the issue. Just to be sure, would there be any other implications of getting rid of the "static" part of the method that would act up in later parts of development? i am quite new and have always used the static method.

Comment: The short answer is no, it's probably okay in this case. But I'd recommend reading some more about the difference between static and instance methods. There are scenarios where one or the other is preferable, and where one or the other is necessary. [Here's something](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members).

Answer (score 0):

You try to call a non-static method in a static method. It causes the problem.

And attention, if you assign with += an event to your button, it will multiply the click event.

It means that if you call 2 times  buttons[i].Click += ChessBlock_clicked; when you will click on your button, it will execute the same method two times.

To release the click event, you can use buttons[i].Click -= ChessBlock_clicked; or before assigning it you can check it it is assigned.